# I run values in redis tags, but these data were not found?

Tags: laravel, redis

I need to run laravel 8 app on my local ubuntu 20.04 server, but I failed to setup my redis server: This app has no predis library in my composer.json file. So running code :

```
try {
    Cache::set('custom_Key', ['key1'=> 'value1', 'key2'=> 'value2']);
    Cache::tags('tagKeyName')->forever('key', $arrayData);
} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    Log::error($exception);
}

$cacheValue = Cache::tags('tagKeyName')->get('key');
\Log::info(' -1 $cacheValue::');
\Log::info($cacheValue);
```

I do not have runtime errors and in log file I see valid values, but checking phpRedisAdmin(I cleared it before) I see empty area and next logics of the app fails, as data from cache were not found. In my .env I have :

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=1200

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Is it env misconfigure of my env? How can I fix this problem ?